# Randoop on Ubuntu/Eclipse-oxygen

Tags: 16.04, automation, testing

I need to write unite tests for my project (being developed in Java 8) using Randoop, how can I configure Randoop on Ubuntu system? I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: I am now able to run Randoop using CLI, but still want to configure Randoop with Eclipse, using whether Maven or Gradle.

Comment: Should I ask this question on other SE community? Like Stack Overflow or Software Engineering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Git official Eclipse Plugin repo, developers indicate:
"This plugin code was removed from the main Randoop repository in October 2015, and Randoop no longer supports communication with the plugin."

Since the Eclipse plugin is not currently supported from within Randoop, you can clone Randoop source code, build and import in Eclipse, but i guess is convenient use it from CLI